# Combine these two equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two equations:

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac {z} {\cos\left(x-\frac {180\lfloor\frac{xy} {180}\rfloor}{y}\right)}$$

which is correct when $\left\lfloor\frac {xy} {180}\right\rfloor$ is odd and...

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac {z} {\cos\left(\frac {180} {y} - \left(x-\frac {180\lfloor\frac{xy} {180}\rfloor}{y}\right)\right)}$$

which is correct when $\left\lfloor\frac {xy} {180}\right\rfloor$ is even.

How can I combine these two equations into one (concise) form?

Comment: What if $\frac{xy}{180}$ is not an integer?

Comment: @AlexR Whoops! Forgot floor symbols on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. Looking carefully you take
$$\cos\left(x- \frac{180\cdot (2k+1)}y\right)$$
In the denominator where $\lfloor \frac{xy}{180} \rfloor \le (2k+1)$ and $k$ is minimal for that to hold. But then
$$k = \Big\lceil (\big\lfloor \frac{xy}{180} \big\rfloor - 1) /2 \Big\rceil$$
Plug this back in to obtain
$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{z}{\displaystyle \cos\left(x - \frac{180 + 360 \left\lceil \frac{\lfloor xy/180 \rfloor - 1}2\right\rceil}y \right)}$$

To check this, just verify that
$$n(k) = 2 \left\lceil \frac{k-1}2 \right\rceil + 1$$
is the smallest odd number not less than $k$.